# What does `exit()` send `status` to, the parent process or the OS kernel?

Tags: c, linux

In Linux,

```
#include <stdlib.h>
void exit(int status);
```

What does `exit()` send `status` to, the parent process or the OS kernel?

APUE says that

> `exit()`  performs  certain  cleanup  processing  and  then
>   returns to the kernel.

But when I run a program in shell, the program returns its exit status to the shell which is its parent process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you're probably aware, Linux (like most Operating Systems) keeps processes separate. That's why the result of `exit` is passed via the kernel to the parent process.

Comment: Specifically, kernel saves it until the parent process requests it through [`wait()`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/waitpid) or one of its friends.